# Recursive Search Function for a Linked List in C

Tags: c, search, recursion, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I made a linked list of cars.
And I'm trying to make a recursive function Search.
Here is what I did.
For some reason this doesn't work.  Please can you explain why and how to fix it?

```
CarroPtr Search(CarroPtr head,int num)
{
   printf("Matricula %d\n", num);

   if (head == NULL)
    {
     return NULL;
    }

   if (head->matricula == num)
    {
     return head->nome;
    }
   else
    {
     head = head->next;
    }

  Search(head, num);

}
```

Comment: Look at your `Search` invoke at the bottom. Hint: It returns something, but you're ignoring that result., Odds are it's caller is interested in that return value, *even if the caller is itself via recursion*.

Comment: You don't always return a value from your function — you should.

Comment: this code is UB since it drops out of a function declared as non void

Comment: What is `head->nome`?  It should be a `CarroPtr`, but it looks more like a name.  You should probably use `return head;` rather than `return head->nome;`.  The `else` is a bit redundant since the `if` does an unconditional return.  The recursive call is also part of the `else` code (it is only executed when the `else` code is executed) — even though it is not in the `else` block.

Comment: well i solve the problem,the error its in the returns. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you mean the following

```
CarroPtr Search(CarroPtr head,int num)
{
    return head == NULL || head->matricula == num ? head : Search( head->next, num );
}
```

Or you can enclose the condition of the ternary operator in parentheses if you think that in this case it will be more readable (though it is not required).

```
CarroPtr Search(CarroPtr head,int num)
{
    return ( head == NULL || head->matricula == num ) ? head : Search( head->next, num );
}
```

As for your code then the function either tries to return objects of different types like `head` and `head->nome` or returns nothing as in the case of the statement with the call of the function

```
Search(head, num);
```

that leads to undefined behavior..

Comment: Your return seems to return a mix of bool and CarroPtr. I suggest making it clearer by using an if within the body of CarroPtr rather than trying to do it all in one line:  if (head==NULL) return NULL; else return (head->matricula == num ? head : Search( head->next, num );

Comment: @ScottK The function returns pointer of the type CarroPtr. The one thing that could be done is enclosing the condition in parentheses though it is not required.

Comment: @Vlad_from_Moscow: I am confused by your solution. Won't "return head == NULL) || ... evaluate to true if head equals NULL? The IF will then short-circuit since TRUE || anything is true. A bool does not seem to match the return type. If head != null, then the other part of the expression is evaluated which return a CarroPtr as expected. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ScottK There is used the so called conditional operator. You are right saying that if head is equal to true then the second operand of the logical OR operator will not be evaluated. But in any case the head will be returned that is the operand after the sign ? will be returned.

Comment: Thanks @Vlad_from_Moscow for the clarification. I missed that the '?' operator has very low precedence. Now that you have added the brackets, it makes it much clearer! Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147216/discussion-between-scottk-and-vlad-from-moscow).